# how can change Back arrow button - android

Tags: android, kotlin, back-button, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

how can I change back button colour to my custom colour programmatically,
for example, green colour

[image: back button image]

Comment: Hi can you copy paste icon vector source ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add below to your button, in the xml:

```
android:tint="@color/my_custom_color"
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: it's not working 
Also, I get my custom colour from the API 
so I have to change it programmatically not from XML